# Does X always has a finite open cover?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Does X always has a finite open cover?

X is a metric space. I think it is false because there is a possibility to
have closed neighborhood near a point in X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the definition of an open cover? For a topological space $X$,  an open cover is a collection of open sets $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$, such that $X = \bigcup_{i \in I} V_i$.  So just take the open cover $\{X\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Every metric space has an open covering consisting of exactly *one* open set, namely $X$ itself.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you please explain more? so, it is true that X always has a finite open cover?

Comment: I don't know what to explain, really!

Comment: {X} is a finite open cover of X.